# Typo3: HTML content element with PHP?

Tags: php, html, typo3

I'm working on an old website (T3 6.2.36). I've added a content element ("special element" -> "pure HTML"). This way I was able to add some javascript functionality via `<script>` tags. Now I need php functionality to generate some dynamic HTML, but not even `<?php echo "test" ?>` works if I put it into the HTML special element. Why not?

Comment: Are you sure php is installed on the server?

Comment: of course, otherwise typo3 wouldn't be working right?

Comment: Did not know typo3...

Comment: It won´t work like that in Typo3. You won´t be able to add PHP Code to the HTML-Backend-Element. You will need to write an extension and put your PHP code in the Controller and link it to the related template. You can then use this in backend as a plugin. It would be like an invitation for Hackers if you would be able to put PHP in there.

Comment: oh god, that sounds awfully complicated :( is this really the only way? I have no idea about writing extensions in typo3 ...

Comment: please specify what dynamic content you want  to generate. as Typoscript is very powerful, you might can do it without PHP.

Comment: I wanted to use PHP to collect all files from multiple directories underneath fileadmin and then put hrefs (downloads) with CSS classes on the page for every file that was found. I need the CSS classes so that later I can hide/show certain downloads depending on which filter button was clicked (javascript).

Answer (score 1):

Since Typo3 is a CMS system that allows users to edit the HTML contents of the website, it is not possible to write PHP directly in the editor.

The [docs](https://typo3.org/help/documentation/) mention `subparts` which will be replaced by another predefined 'part'. I don't know Typo3 to know how to manage `subparts` and if they can hold PHP code. But it might be what you need.

[All about subparts](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TemplatingTutorial/Tasks/WorkingHTML/HtmlTemplate/Index.html#subparts)

Comment: I wouldn´t recommend to use it like in this doc. This is not up to date and will cause problems when updating. He should either get into Extbase, Fluid and how to write your own stuff with it.

Comment: Okay :p I'll leave the answer as a reference to 'how not to do it'

Comment: Oh let me revert my comment, subparts seem to be still working in the latest release. But anyway, you need to get deeper into typoscript for it, which is even more complicated. So it seems to be ok to do it for in terms of updating and stuff, but in my opinion it is not a nice way. It always depends on what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Marcel Wasilewski's comment actually is the correct answer:

It's not possible to add PHP code using the "Insert HTML" content element, because that would be a big security issue. Anybody with a backend user account would be able to run any PHP code on the server.

The desired functionality (read file lists and make HTML elements for each file) should be implemented as an extension.